# Connect Samsung Chromebook to a projector

Tags: chromebook

I have a [Samsung Chromebook](https://www.google.com/intl/ms/chrome/devices/samsung-chromebook.html#ss-cb), that I'm trying to connect to a Mitsubishi projector via a HDMI to VGA conversion cable. To my understanding, the Chromebook should automatically mirror the display once plugged in. However, when I plug it in, nothing happens on the Chromebook OR the projector display. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried enabling some of the flags, e.g., [Hardware Mirror-Mode](chrome://flags#enable-hardware_mirror-mode), etc?  You may want to take another look at any other mirroring-related flags, I can't verify as I don't have the same hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Many laptops have a function key that activates the projector or toggles between mirrored and extended desktops.

On the chromebook, try Ctrl + MaxScreen.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried this.